# Spring Boot - в MySQL данные при отправке формой пишутся не в utf-8 (кракозябры)

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, spring-boot

Добрый день.

Есть простое CRUD приложение на Spring Boot.

В IDE все работает как надо, проблем нет.

Сгенерил WAR, задеплоил в TomCat - там тоже все работает, кроме кодировки при отправке данных из формы - пишутся кракозябры, т.е. вместо "тест" в базу уходит "Ð¢ÐµÑÑ".
Гуглил, но увы...

В application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.generate.ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8

spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
```

В pom.xml есть:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

В web.xml есть:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

В Application.java есть:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

В .jsp присутствуют:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

и

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Что еще я упустил?

Update:
Урезанный работающий проект
http://web-site.ru/Library.rar

Comment: Для проверки попробуйте вывести данные в консоли, прежде чем они будут записываться в БД, если все ок, то нужно смотреть БД. `schema` в БД должна быть создана с кодировкой `utf8_general_ci` , а не по дефолту в `latin1` , проверьте эту кодировку.

Comment: Посмотрел tomcat8-stdout.log, там "???µ???? 1" вместо "тест 1". В БД разумеется utf8_general_ci

Comment: Онлайн конвертер расшифровал `Ð¢ÐµÑÑ` как `ыцее` , а исходная кодировка `cp866` . По дефолту у консоли windows `cp866` и нет поддержки utf8, есть подозрения, что через нее и смотрите. Добавьте информацию где запускаете проект (локально, удаленно, какая ось), как и через что смотрите логи. А в идеале выложите минимальный воспроизводимый пример на гитхаб, или в вопрос.

Comment: Запускаю на Win 10 на localhost, в Idea все ок, после деплоя в TomCat - кракозябры... Параметры подключения к MySQL в application.properties, таблица создается с помощью data.sql

Comment: Попробуй убрать фильтр в web.xml, похоже на то, что фильтр применяется 2 раза.

Comment: Да! Дело было именно в этом! Теперь все работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в неправильном использовании `CharacterEncodingFilter`. Данный фильтр использовался в 2 местах одновременно:

1. в файле web.xml
2. регистрировался отдельным бином в java конфигурации

Необходимо удалить фильтр в файле web.xml, и после этого из браузера в приложение будут приходить запросы в нормальной кодировке.